# PHP CMS: Directly Editing Content (no DB)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, content-management-system

Is there any harm in a CMS calling a PHP script to directly edit an HTML file, without storing the input in a database?  As long as all inputs are thoroughly sanitized, nothing comes to mind that would be detrimental.

This approach wouldn't open an application up to any security issues that wouldn't be present if storing the data in, say, a MySQL database, correct?

Answer (score 1):

There are other issues here besides security.  Without a database, it'll be hard and slow to search your data based on things other than filenames.  For example, you want items created between a certain set of times.  Also, Read/Writes to files are slower than read/writes to databases.  And, what if two users try to read/write the same content?  A database that supports transactions can take of this problem, but read/writing files, not so much.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of apps do that, and I wouldn't say it's impossible to do it securely, but there is a fundamental difference in having an app that's set up to write to files rather than to write to a database. (Stored procedures aside, silly use of eval() aside, rare flaws in database systems that allow data to be executed as code aside) data inside a database is harder to make executable than a file in the filesystem. In the case where your sanitization and logic about where to put the file and what to name it are foolproof, you will be ok with files or with db. But in the case where an attacker is able to get malicious data through, or cause the app to save the file in a different location, consider the difference in what would happen with direct filesystem storage vs. database storage. With a database, the worst they could do would be to overwrite parts of your database you didn't want them to, with data you didn't like. That's not completely harmless and they could do things like write XSS attacks into the db that would end up displaying on the page, etc., but it's not nearly as bad as what they could if they could get arbitrary data into an arbitrary file in the filesystem.